# Cross platform UIImage NSImage in NSData format

Tags: ios, macos, uiimage, nsimage

I have an app on the mac and iPad that stores many images in the core data backed database. Previously they were images from URL's so there was no worries I just went from URL to data. But now I am creating thumbnails from the URL then saving it into the database. The issue I have is that I want to store them as NSData, but cant seem to find a format that I can store using the mac app, that the ipad version will be able to recognize and create an image from.

I tried,

```
NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
```

but then I get an error that Ipad does not recognize the data in DB and is incompatible.

anyone have ideas? or found a solution to this problem?

Comment: have you tried converting the images to `NSData` using `UIImagePNGRepresentation()`? that's only available on iOS. on OSX you could try something like the `PNGRepresentationOfImage` method here: https://gist.github.com/1178403

Comment: @Mike K, that is correct.  Add it as an answer instead of a comment!

Comment: I went at it in a round about way, ... but PNGRepresentationOfImage did work on mac and only had to use UIImage imageFromData on the iOS version.  Thanks! I cant mark this as correct though until it's an "answer"

Answer (score -3, accepted):

For the mac side I did

```
NSImage *smallImageGuy ....
NSData *pngRepOfImage = [self PNGRepresentationOfImage:smallImageGuy];
```

and on iOS side

```
UIImage *superDuperAwsomeImageGuy = [UIImage imageWithData:"NSData in DB"];
```

and TaDa!

Comment: What have you done in `[self PNGRepresentationOfImage:smallImageGuy];`

Comment: @KapilChoubisa Convert the image to NSData (basically a string of text that tells the software the color of each pixel and the dimensions of the image and whatnot, because most databases only store strings)

Comment: You didn't really answer your question, to accept this as a proper answer you must show the content of your `PNGRepresentationOfImage:` method.. Which I assume came from this source ?
http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2011/Aug/msg01102.html